# Where can I find Kala?

Tags: diablo-iii

She drops a lore book (["Kala's Poem"](http://d3db.com/lore/i/kalas-poem)) in Act 2, but I don't remember meeting her. I've seen [a cropped screenshot](http://d3db.com/static/uploads/original/01d92b52d888d7fe75e30e1926291c38.png) of her in the Hidden Camp. When does she appear, and where?

Comment: Can only give a partial answer, she spawned after finding the entry ''A Love Letter'' written by Solan, afraid I cannot remember where I found it. Had no luck in finding out where the Love Letter is from, but the poem by Solan speaks of his love rising out of the Oasis so possible it's in a random dungeon in The Dahlgur Oasis

Comment: I found the Solan book in Dahlgur Oasis; but I had all my interactions with Kala *before* this so that is not a requirement to spawn her (she is always accessible afaik)

Comment: Hmm okay, never had the option to talk to her before I found the Love Letter and since they're both poems I assumed there was a connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She stands around at the hidden camp **before Quest 8**, right at the edge of the cliff. Like Captain Rumford in New Tristram she always only has one topic at a time, and one of these topics will make her drop her poem.[image: Kala in the hidden camp]

Comment: Thanks—she isn't around after Quest 7, which was my issue. I'll add a screenshot

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that...

Answer (score 1):

For Kala, go back to quest 7, then go talk to her in the Hidden Camp.  I just found the Love Letter in a Keepsake Box in Dahlgur Oasis, just NE of the northern most waypoint.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find Kala's Poem after I spoke to Kulle in Act 2, Quest #7 Blood and Sand with the conversation with Kala "Noble Dreams".